# Remember Page Position Using Two Lines of Script

Tags: php, javascript

In all major browsers, except Internet Explorer, the following script returns the page to its previous vertical position on reload:

```
<?php $y = $_COOKIE["y"]; ?> //in head tag before any output
```

and

```
<?php
print "<body onScroll=\"document.cookie='y=' + window.pageYOffset\" onLoad='window.scrollTo(0,$y)'>";
```

Can someone please tell me how I would modify this code to remember the page's vertical position in IE?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp) :

IE 8 and earlier does not support this property, but may use "document.body.scrollLeft" and "document.body.scrollTop" instead.

Comment: Thanks, AlecTMH, but my question is How do I modify my code to accomplish this? I obtained this tip from another forum but am not a javascript person.

Comment: Try to replace `window.pageYOffset` with `document.body.scrollTop`

Comment: I thought of this myself but, unfortunately, it doesn't work. Do you have any other suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to do basic IE/not-IE browser detection:

```
if(document.all) {  //if IE
    //code
} else {            //if not IE
    //code
}
```

You should be able to combine this with AlecTMH's `document.body.scrollLeft` and `document.body.scrollTop` suggestion to get where you're going. But you're likely going to have to write a function for it and then call that in `onScroll()`.

I'm not exactly a JavaScript wiz, but...

```
function blah() {
    if(document.all) {  //if IE
        document.cookie='y=' + document.body.scrollTop
    } else {            //if not IE
        document.cookie='y=' + window.pageYOffset
    }
}
```

...might almost be functional code.

Comment: Wow! I thought the solution would be a lot more complex than this. I'll try it.